# Pymongo: can I query a pymongo query object?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a query in python using pymongo that works very well. It returns entries for a single user. Later on the script, I want to narrow this results. I want to iterate over each day, and query again for this user how many entries are there on this day alone.

The question is: Do I need to make a new query, or can I query over the object I already have?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply filter the results that you have, instead of hitting the database again with a new query ?

```
todays_entries = [item for item in iterable if function(item)]
```

Explanation:

The result of your query will be a list of entries. I guess you are using that list in some way first, and later in the code you want to count all entries that was create today.

Python has a awesome way of filtering lists. Documentation for this can be found here:
[Python Filter Function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

The code I wrote above is just a more pythonic way of using that function. As I dont have your code I can only guess what it might look like for you. Maybe something like this:

```
todays_entries = [entry for entry in all_entries if entry.date == todays_date]
```

Ofcourse: entry.date has to be in a comparable format with todays_date

Comment: I have a query with pymongo like this: `myDocs = db.collection.find({'userID':myUser})`... sorry, but I don't understand your answer :-(. I'm not the most profesional python programmer. Can you explain me again, taking into account my code?

Comment: Its up to you - you could issue a new query with extra filtering or do the filter like @bobmoff describes in python.  If you have all the data anyway - it may be easier to just filter in python.